# Selecting div inside iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to select a div inside an iframe with jQuery. But I can't get it to work.
Any suggestions what could be the issue here?

**Parent HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Selector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://[sameDomainAsParent]/selector/template.html" id="selectorFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
        $("#selectorFrame").contents().find("#name").css("border", "2px solid red");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.template.css">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="color"></div>
    <div id="name">Name</div>
    <div id="title">Title</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to wait for the iframe to be loaded. So the final jQuery script will be:

```
$(function() {
   $("#selectorFrame").bind("load",function(){
      $("#selectorFrame").contents().find("#name").css("border", "2px solid green");
   });
});
```